# Cron jobs for PHP in Google App Engine always fails

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

Am building an application in google app engine using php.
My application needs to write & read to a file every 1 min so i thought cron jobs would be a best choice.
i am new to cron jobs in php. i followed their documentation in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/cron)
 this is my cron.yaml file

```
cron:
- description: test cron job
  url: /cron_jobs
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

---

this is my app.yaml with the necessary handler for the cron job

```
application: my-app-id
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /cron_jobs
  script: sample_cron.php
  login: admin
```

---

in sample_cron.php i have used file_put_contents() to write to a file in my default gcs bucket. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$object_url = "gs://my-app-id.appspot.com/beta.txt";
$content = "Entry every 1 min";
$options = ['gs' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents($object_url, $content, 0, $ctx);
?>
```

But each time in the admin console it is mentioned that the cron job fails . I have tried to write a code that inserts a record into a table and that doesn't work too.

What am i doing wrong?

---

i changed the cron.yaml file's url entry as

```
    cron:
- description: test cron job
  url: /cron_jobs/sample_cron.php
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

and the app.yaml file as

```
- url: /cron_jobs/sample_cron
script: sample_cron.php
  login: admin
```

now the cron job succeeds every time but the file is not updated. I run the same code normally and the file is updated. What could be the problem with cron job in gae? How can i find out what is going wrong? i have checked the logs.

---

The problem was in app.yaml file. I changed to `script: /cron_jobs/sample_cron.php` and now it works..